What is the most compact way to cram a list of integers into a string?
Objective:
Decrease the size of an array of integers like this: "[12, 1, -34, 55, 13, 341, 11, 56, 321, -3422, 1222, -4, 237]" while being able to convert it back to its original state. The compressed output must be a string.
Reason:
Having excessively long strings causes the database manager I'm using to freeze when interacting with it. (Strings are used as the storage format for variable types like Arrays.)
Context:
I am essentially storing a list of grid coordinates like so: [Vector3(1,2,3), Vector3(4,5,6)] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
I'm building this in gdscript.

My best attempt at cramming the numbers of the first integer array example together results in this:
"c1-y.Td,y1.bU,w1-ym,cm-4,n7"
By assigning coupled numbers > 9 to a non-numeric character (e.g. 10 = a, 11 = b, 61 = Z)
and only placing commas between converted numbers composed of multiple characters (and using the "-" symbol as a sorta comma as well (it's somewhat complicated)). This is a 48% size decrease on average excluding whitespace (tested 200 randomly generated arrays).
Question:
Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Final Edit:
Here is my solution in gdscript in case anyone wants it.
extends Node
var negative_character_index = 50000
#skip all white space characters as well as "." and ","  and "()" 
#these are used for special cases
var start_char = 47

func num_to_char(num: int):
    var x = abs(num)
    if x > negative_character_index:
        #too large
        return
    else:
        x += start_char
        if num < 0:
            x += negative_character_index
        var char = String.chr(x)
        return char

func char_to_num(char : String):
    var x = char.unicode_at(0) - start_char
    if x == null:
        #maybe negative_character_index was changed
        breakpoint
    
    if x > negative_character_index:
        x -= negative_character_index
        x *= -1
        
    return x

#shorten int 
func int_to_compact_int_string(n:int):
    
    var compact_n = ""
    #largest convertable number
    var head = ""
    
    var last_head_int = null
    var last_char = null
    
    var get_zeros_code = func(head):
        
        var zeros = 0
        
        if head.begins_with("0"):
            
            for char2 in head:
                if char2 == "0":
                    
                    zeros += 1
                else:
                    break
            if head.right(1) == "0":
                
                zeros -=1
            if zeros > 0:
                return "("+str(zeros)+")"
        return ""
    
    for num in str(n):
        
        
        
        head += num
        print(head)
        if num != "-":
            
            var head_int = str_to_var(head)
            var char = get_zeros_code.call(head) + num_to_char(head_int)
            print(char)
            if last_head_int != null && char == null:
                compact_n += last_char
                head = ""
                head += num
                
                last_head_int = str_to_var(head)
                last_char = get_zeros_code.call(head) + num_to_char(last_head_int)
            else:
                last_head_int = head_int
                last_char = char
        print("~~~")
    if head != "":
        print(head)
        print(last_char)
        print("~~~")
        compact_n += last_char
    
    
    
    return compact_n



func int_arr_to_compact_str(int_arr):
    var compact_str = ""
    var is_multi = false
    for n in int_arr:
        
        var compact_n:String = int_to_compact_int_string(n)
        if compact_n.length() > 1: #seperate multicharacter compact numbers
            compact_str += ","
            is_multi = true
        elif is_multi:
            compact_str += "."
            is_multi =false
        
        
        
        compact_str += compact_n
        
    return compact_str


func new_compact_int_string_to_int(compact_n:String):
    
    
    var n = ""
    
    var is_zeros = false
    var zeros = ""
    
    for char in compact_n:
        if char == "(":
            is_zeros = true
            zeros = ""
        elif char == ")":
            is_zeros = false
            var i = 0
            
            while i < str_to_var(zeros):
                
                n += "0"
                i+=1
        elif is_zeros:
            zeros += char
        else:
            var index = char_to_num(char)
            if index > negative_character_index:
                index -= negative_character_index
                index *= -1
            
            n += str(index)
    
    
    return str_to_var(n)




func new_compact_str_to_int_arr(compact_str):
    var int_arr = []
    
    var is_multi = false
    var multi_compiler = ""
    for char in compact_str:
        if char == ',' || char == '.':
            is_multi = char == ','
            
            #end compiler
            if multi_compiler.length() >0:
                int_arr.append(new_compact_int_string_to_int(multi_compiler))
                multi_compiler = ""
            
            
            
            
            
        else:
            if is_multi:
                multi_compiler += char
            else:
                int_arr.append(new_compact_int_string_to_int(char))
    
    if multi_compiler.length() > 0:
        int_arr.append(new_compact_int_string_to_int(multi_compiler))
        multi_compiler = ""
    
    return int_arr

func _ready():
    var arr2 = [237, 50001, -5000000003, 250000000]
    
    #print("---")
    #for i in range(999):
        #print(String.chr(i)+" -> "+str(i))
    #print("---")
    
    print(arr2)
    var comp = int_arr_to_compact_str(arr2)
    print(comp)
    var r_arr2 = new_compact_str_to_int_arr(comp)
    print(r_arr2)


the most compact way to cram a list of integers into a string such that they can be retrieved/restored.

What is the range of the integers?

You could convert to UTF-16 codes (0 - 65535) with a sign:


const arr = [12, 1, -34, 55, 13, 341, 11, 56, 321, -3422, 1222, -4, 237];

const result = arr.map(n => (Math.sign(n) < 0 ? '-' : '') + String.fromCharCode(Math.abs(n))).join('');
console.log(result);
console.log(arr.join(',').length, '=>', result.length);

//decode
const out = [];
for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
  const sign = result[i]==='-'?-1:1;
  if(sign<0) i++;
  out.push(result[i].charCodeAt()*sign);
}
console.log(...out);



You can use the first bit to store the sign, though the range is narrowed to 32768 max:


const arr = [12, 1, -34, 55, 13, 341, 11, 56, 321, -3422, 1222, -4, 237];

const result = arr.map(n => {
  let c = Math.abs(n);
  c = (c << 1) + (Math.sign(n) < 0 ? 1 : 0);
  return String.fromCharCode(c);
}).join('');
console.log(result);
console.log(arr.join(',').length, '=>', result.length);

//decode
const out = [];
for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
  const n = result[i].charCodeAt();
  out.push((n >> 1) * (n & 1 === 1 ? -1 : 1));
}
console.log(...out);




I'll start by saying that the encoding you came up with is not bad.  There's a little room for improvement, though.
To obtain a "perfect" encoding, you only need to do 3 things:

Choose your character set.  You say that the output is a "string", but is it a string with arbitrary 8-bit chars, or UTF-8, or UTF-16, or ISO-8859-1, or what?  Regardless, you need to decide which characters you have available to you.  It looks like you're currently using 63: 0-9, A-Z, a-z, plus minus and comma.  You probably have at least 100 you can use.  Maybe much more.  Using more characters let you put more data in the same-size string, as you've already discovered.
Make sure that nearly every string of your chosen characters corresponds to a valid input.  Every invalid string is a missed opportunity for compression.  It looks like ",,," is invalid in your current scheme, for example, and that means that there's an input that currently maps to a longer string that could have been mapped to that one instead.
Make sure that every character in your character set is equally likely to appear in the output after any valid prefix.  That basically means that your strings appear so random that given any prefix, you cannot guess anything about the next one.  If this condition doesn't hold, then you are missing out on some possible compression.  How much you're missing out is calculated by the Kullback-Leibler divergence, but I'm guessing you're not quite ready for that.

This all sounds not-too-hard, but in reality step 3 is the entire job of lossless data compression.  It would be easy, except that the phrase "equally likely" is ambiguous.  It assumes a statistical model of the input, and the better this model is, the more compression you can get.  These models can be quite complicated.
Because it's really so hard, if you really care, then you should usually leverage a robust compressor, like:

gzip-compress your array
base64-encode the output, or use whatever the equivalent of base64 encoding is for your chosen character set.

If you don't care that much, though, then here is a simple schema that is optimal for common distributions of integers that are symmetric around 0.  Lets say that your character set consists of M characters, which we will refer to as "digits" from 0 to M-1.  To encode an integer:
// encode integer to string with M digits

encodeInt(int n) -> string:
    // exactly one representation for 0
    if (n === 0):
        return digits[0];
    // range of remaining digits
    rangestart = 1
    rangeend = M
    if (n > 0):
        // N is positive. move first possibility to 0
        n-=1
        // use lower half of range
        rangeend = ceil((rangeend + rangestart)/2)
    else:
        // N is negative.  Flip sign move first possibility to 0
        n = -n - 1
        // use upper half of range
        rangestart = ceil((rangestart + rangeend)/2)

    T = thresholds[0]    
    if (n < T):
        // n is small, encode in one character
        return digits[rangestart+n];

    //n is big
    //remove small encodings from range
    rangestart += T
    range = rangeend-rangestart

    //Encode n%range in the first digit, and the rest in next digits
    return digits[n%range] + encodePos(floor(n/range), 1) // + is string concatenation

// encode positive integer to string with M digits

encodePos(int n, int place) -> string:
    T = thresholds[place]
    if (n < T):
        // n is small, encode in one character
        return digits[n];

    // n is big
    range = M - T
    return digits[n%range] + encodePos(floor(n/range), place+1)

Notice that there are parameters I didn't specify -- the thresholds array.
In order to get an "optimal" encoding, these thresholds should be chosen so that the probability of seeing n >= or < the threshold is proportional to the number of characters available above or below the threshold.
This encoding is self-delimiting, so to encode an entire array, just encode all the numbers and concatenate them together.  There is no need for , or other separator.

This seems like an XY problem - assuming you don't have millions of these collections, could you prepare a mapping to some new lookup table and get them from another table?
You will need to consider how these will map back, but may be able to generally get a nicer solution, perhaps serializing each individual Vector (or really just its members) instead of N vectors members into single fields or N unpacked vectors, adding NULL fields to track various lengths, etc.
Table 1



key
value1
value2
t2 key




foo
first
A
1


bar
second
B
2


baz
third
C
3



Table 2



key

















1
12
1
-34
55
13
341
11
56
321
-3422
1222
-4
237




This is also a good solution. though I'd rather all my data for this be in the same table if the cramming works well enough.
Less overhead (in terms of not having to fetch my data from more than one table) seems better to me.

I don't have a way to test your specific scenario, but that's really the benefit to multiple tables ; the humble SELECT * FROM _ JOIN _ ON _ WHERE _ is amazingly fast and should result in a comparable total data transfer .. though note you may get additional slowdown and gains from a design where you have multiple tables of integers with different column lengths to account for very different vector unpack lengths
